Save dynamic RDLC report as PDF with the correct page size
So far Im printing a RDLC report in a POS printer which is dynamic. The problem is when I try to save it as a PDF because I get a huge white space in it. Thats because the report size is the whole roll of paper
width 3.14961in
Height 128.9764in
the body size is 3.14961in, 11.74421in but it will grow and shrink depending on the data
This is the function that converts to PDF
    public void PrintReportToPDF(LocalReport report, string fileNameXML)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exporting report to PDF...");

        int paperWidthHundredthsOfInch = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize.Width;
        int paperHeightHundredthsOfInch = report.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize.Height;

        double paperWidthInches = paperWidthHundredthsOfInch / 100.0;
        double paperHeightInches = paperHeightHundredthsOfInch / 100.0;

        string deviceInfo = $@"
<DeviceInfo>
    <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>
    <PageWidth>{paperWidthInches}in</PageWidth>
    <PageHeight>{paperHeightInches}in</PageHeight>
    <MarginTop>0.0in</MarginTop>
    <MarginLeft>0.0in</MarginLeft>
    <MarginRight>0.0in</MarginRight>
    <MarginBottom>0.0in</MarginBottom>
</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;

        // Render the report to PDF format
        byte[] renderedBytes = report.Render(
            "PDF", // Render format
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);

        //   string pdfPath = @"C:\Users\juanm\Desktop\2024\report.pdf";
        string pdfPath = Path.ChangeExtension(fileNameXML, ".pdf");
        Console.WriteLine("PDF Path "+ pdfPath);


        // Save the rendered report as a PDF file
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            fs.Write(renderedBytes, 0, renderedBytes.Length);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Report saved as PDF successfully!");
    }

And I know Im using the whole report size as the page size for the PDF but if I dont know the height how can I achieve it?
Thanks for the help
Save the pdf with the correct height
